# Architecture for managing files within a specific web application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, architecture, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 (with Apache) in order to develop a web application. I need some (technical) advice/solution to design **a part** of my application.

### Here is the context of my problem for this part:

In my web application, I need to store files (images, or videos of 150Mo max) uploaded by different users. A user can share some of his files with others that it will choose. For example:
 "I've uploaded image1.png and I would like to share it only with Bob and Alice. If I delete image1.png, this file must still be accessible by Bob and Alice until all of them don't want it anymore (a batch maybe run daily to delete it if no user is linked to this file)".

### Questions:

- For managing uploaded files, I would like to allow a user to upload some files without blocking him. He must be able to browse through all pages of my web application during its uploads and see their status (for example, in a progress bar). **How can I do that? Is a PHP script and Ajax would be sufficient? Is this possible with Jquery plugin like jQuery File Upload?**
- To store my files, currently, I'm using a single directory. Also, I use a Mysql database to build the logic around the file management (e.g: "image1.png has been uploaded by me and it's url is currently shared with Alice and Bob. They can download it"). For the moment, it's work fine. Only Alice and Bob can see my file. But I don't know if this a good way for an application that could be grow (in terms of files and users). **Is this a good architecture (single directory+database)? or I must use physical directory per user?**
- **Could I get any advice around performance and optimization regarding my application?**

Any help would be appreciate. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1) bad idea / you'd have to do the upload in a separate window (or pop-up)

the page has to remain open until the upload is completed, I'd be surprised if you could pause it on page exit then restore it where it was after the next page has been loaded (& it'd be a lot of work for maybe not so many benefits); that is unless your app is contained within a single page. i used to allow using back-office app during uploads but it ended up causing many unexpected issues depending on user behaviour, now I freeze the bo during uploads and they wait, much safer, no bugs, no fix, no hassle

2) mostly depends if you have to iterate/search through the files in the file system, ie not from a db query pointing to files on the server

3) no you have to create a separate question for each specific issue, but you might as well google jquery optimization

me I guess i'd store pointer to files in a db table with a system to cache query result in json in files (cache updated every time the user delete/add files) (so even if users are plenty queries to db remain low) + i would allow multiple file selection + leave users waiting for their upload to be completed (& also for server file treatment if any - except probably video editing - too long) - i don't like popup

Comment: Please, could you give me more details about your answer?
1) Why would be a bad idea? What are the drawbacks of this approach?
2) I'm not sure of the meaning of your "iterate through the files" but I think it will be the case. For example, to get all files uploaded by a specific user. 
3) Sorry for this. For me, it was a question directly related to the previous points. It's not only related with jquery but with what I'm going to do regarding the 2 other points.

Comment: the page has to remain open until the upload is completed, I'd be surprised if you could pause it on page exit then restore it where it was after the next page has been loaded (& it'd be a lot of work for maybe not so many benefits); that is unless your app is contained within a single page. i used to allow using backoffice app during uploads but it ended up causing many unexpected issues depending on user behaviour, now I freeze the bo during uploads and they wait, much safer, no bugs, nof fix

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanations. My problem is with this approach, users must wait during uploads and can't use other parts of the web application.

Comment: & why would they ? not so many people are that versatile ! anyhow build your app on ajax requests, it's the only way

Answer (score -1):

> For managing uploaded files, I would like to allow a user to upload some files without blocking him. He must be able to browse through all pages of my web application during its uploads and see their status (for example, in a progress bar). How can I do that? Is a PHP script and Ajax would be sufficient? Is this possible with Jquery plugin like jQuery File Upload?

As soon, as user leaves page, upload gets canceled. However, this is posible using AJAX (whole application written to use advantages of AJAX). I would not do that.

> To store my files, currently, I'm using a single directory. Also, I use a Mysql database to build the logic around the file management (e.g: "image1.png has been uploaded by me and it's url is currently shared with Alice and Bob. They can download it"). For the moment, it's work fine. Only Alice and Bob can see my file. But I don't know if this a good way for an application that could be grow (in terms of files and users). Is this a good architecture (single directory+database)? or I must use physical directory per user?

If folder stores a lot of files, performance degrades.
I would store files in subdirectories.

```
$hash = md5("image.png"); // let's say it produces "abcdefgh...." hash
$directory = "{$hash[0]}{$hash[1]}/{$hash[2]}{$hash[3]}/{$hash[4]}{$hash[5]}"; // then file/folder structure would be "ab/cd/ef/image.png";
```

This way, you can get folder structure anytime from file name.

> Could I get any advice around performance and optimization regarding my application?

See previous answer. I can't come up with any other "problem" - do not create problem before implementation ;)